# Standardizing PHP + CSS to not utilize string parsing

Tags: php, html, css

I apologize for the poor title.  Given the following code:

```
<?php  

    $css = 'foo-'.$data['style'];  
    $html= "<table><tr><td class='{$css}>styled! /> </tr>  </table>;
?>
```

where `[style]` returns a value of:  `'bar','baz','apple'`

how can I correctly strip this out and make it html+css standard instead of this strange PHP parsing?

To clarify 'strange':  I cannot open this in a browser as a standard HTML page, that is what I want to do.

Comment: aren't you lacking some quotes here and there?

Comment: Is `$data['style']` an array?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How is this strange PHP parsing? You're just using a variable as filler.

Comment: @DanLee its strange because it doesn't stand alone if i open it in a browser.

Comment: Just put your markup outside of the <?php ?> tags.  <?text data ?> is the format of a xml Processing instruction so if you have a xml compatible doctype then the browser should ignore all PI's it doesn't understand.

Comment: Does `$data['style']` return an array `['bar','baz','apple']` ?

Comment: What does the raw HTML look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table><tr><td class='foo-<?= $data["style"] ?>' /> </tr>  </table>
```

or

```
<table><tr><td class='<?= "foo-".$data["style"] ?>' /> </tr>  </table>
```

of you can do

```
$style = "foo-".$data["style"];
?>
<table><tr><td class='<?= $style ?>' /> </tr>  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code:

```
<?php  
$css = 'foo-'.$data['style'];  
$html= "<table><tr><td class='{$css}>styled! /> </tr>  </table>;
?>
```

Seems there are some error please correct this:

```
<?php  
$css = 'foo-'.$data['style'];  
$html= "<table><tr><td class=".$css.">styled! </td></tr></table>";
echo $html;
?>
```

else you can write in html+css standard:

```
<?php  
$css = 'foo-'.$data['style'];  
?>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="<?php echo $css; ?>">styled!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i am not sure please check on that in your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'bar','baz','apple' are separate css class. Which will concat with foo-. I mean foo-bar, foo-baz etc. If so then you have to explode each class like this way.

```
<?php
 $css_arr = explode(',',$data['style']);
$css_all_class = implode(' foo-',$css_arr);
$css_all_class  = "foo-".$css_all_class ;
//$css_all_class = " foo-bar foo-baz foo-apple"
?>

<table>
   <tr>
      <td class="<?php echo $css_all_class; ?>">styled!</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want a thing like this.  "<table>
   <tr>
      <td class="foo-bar foo-baz foo-apple">styled!</td>
   </tr>
</table>". If yes it should work.